# Can my fancy shirt be as tough as that guy's magical platemail?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, armor

Not as in armor bonus, but with the enchantment. If my ninja or duelist is wearing a really nice shirt in place of armor, can they have heavy fortification (or any armor enchantment) added to that shirt as though it were armor?

I can understand not getting an armor bonus from a +1 robe, but what about the other equivalent benefits like silent moves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: **Maybe.**

Under the 3.5 ruleset this is not an option but some DMs allow in their games all the 3.0e material that has never been revised.

If this is the case, a 3e supplement (Arms and Equipment Guide IIRC) states that any item that gives armor bonuses can be enchanted as if it was an armor.

This includes the infamous Bracers of Armor and the similar object Harness of Armor that does the same but is worn on the body slot (Harness of Armor is detailed in Lost Empires of Faerun).
That's not a shirt but I guess you had nothing important in the "armor" slot anyways.

If you're looking for a tunic (torso slot), the Vest of the Archmagi, detailed in Magic Item compendium should give you the armor bonus you need for further enhancing it. This item has an almost Epic price so it's not viable for further enchanting until character level 21.

If you're just looking for another way to get fortification, there's an enhancedd Ring of Protection in Waterdeep, City of Splendors that could solve your problem as well. (But no silent moves ring, unfortunately)

---

For getting +1 to +5 enhancements on a nonmagical shirt (or on your vest of resistance), magic vestment does the trick. Ask your party wizard or cleric for some.

Comment: My understanding is that any item can be enchanted essentially any way.  They usually just try to identify certain properties to certain items as a flavor thing.  "Bracers of Armor" and "Boots of Elvenkind" make a lot more sense than "Cap of Flame Strike" or "Whetstone of Wisdom"

Comment: You're right, I absolutely forgot the "different slot, augmented price" effect.
I always thought it worked for those effects that are enchanted upon wondrous items and rings.
I'm not sure if it works with enchantments that specifically work on suits of armor only.

I don't have my manuals with me, can someone check?

Comment: Ah, had forgotten to check the magic item compendium. Nope, just looking for something armor equivalent so this char can have armor enchantments too. It's a ninja.